# ConTeXt : how to go after float?

Tags: graphics, context

When one uses \placefloat[right] with ConTeXt, it automatically wraps the text around the float, which is generally very useful.
However, if I need to go at the first line after the float, I don't know how to do. Is there a command to make the following MWE work ?

```
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\useexternalfigure[ctanlion][http://www.ctan.org/lion/ctan_lion_350x350.png][width=5cm]
\starttext
\placefigure[right,none]{}{\externalfigure[ctanlion]}
This text is placed left to the figure, which is exactly what I want.
% A command here ?
I would like this second text to be on the first line below the figure.
\stoptext
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `\flushsidefloatsafterpar` or `\flushsidefloats`

```
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\useexternalfigure[ctanlion][http://www.ctan.org/lion/ctan_lion_350x350.png][width=5cm]
\starttext
\placefigure[right,none]{}{\externalfigure[ctanlion]}
\flushsidefloatsafterpar
This text is placed left to the figure, which is exactly what I want.   

I would like this second text to be on the first line below the figure.

\placefigure[right,none]{}{\externalfigure[ctanlion]}
This text is placed left to the figure, which is exactly what I want.

\flushsidefloats
I would like this second text to be on the first line below the figure.
\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `tall` keyword to let the figure flow only around the following paragraph and let the rest continue after it.

```
\useexternalfigure[ctanlion][http://www.ctan.org/lion/ctan_lion_350x350.png][width=5cm]

\starttext

\placefigure[right,tall,none]{}{\externalfigure[ctanlion]}
\input  knuth

\stoptext
```

[image: Limit wrap floats to a single paragraph]